# php foreach as $var 'Undefined variable'

Tags: php, foreach, undefined

The undefined variable is `$new_string`.

I wrote this little script because I needed it, (don't ask why).

```
    $string  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // just used as an example

    // $string becomes "badcfehgjilknmporqtsvuxwzy"

    $now_in_pairs = str_split($string, 2);

    $reverse = array_map('strrev', $now_in_pairs);

    foreach($reverse as $r)   { 

    $new_string .= $r;  

    }

    echo $new_string;
```

I know I could simply say, `$new_string = NULL` at the start to avoid the Undefined variable but that doesn't help me to understand why it isn't defined.

In very layman's terms, `$r` equals the value of each pairs in the array?

How can `$new_string` be undefined when it equals `$r`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($reverse as $r)   { 
    $new_string .= $r;  
    }
```

`$new_string .= $r;` means `$new_string = $new_string . $r;` Here you are appending `$r` to the value of variable `$new_string` which is not declared or defined before this code ie, which doesn't exist. You can solve this issue by declaring the variable above `foreach` like :

```
$new_string="";
foreach($reverse as $r)   { 
        $new_string .= $r;  
        }
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you. I assumed the first loop would be considered the equals and the following loops be the appended. My assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is looking for solution where $new_string doesnt need to be initialized beforehand.

The solution is to use the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function of PHP

```
$new_string = implode($reverse);
//another usage with glue parameter:
//$new_string = implode('', $reverse);
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Although I didn't know the name, Implode was the function I was actually looking for when I stumbled upon that I could use .= $r to combine the output of the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no error** in the output of your program:-

http://codepad.org/9FDqrh3D

Its giving gthe correct output for $new_string

Comment: @abhinsit Sorry I forgot to mention that the code works as planned. I've been using it. I opened the error_log and saw the page full of undefined variable notices that I didn't expect to find.

Comment: Sure, when suppressing error_reporting, the notice won't be shown, but the problem still exists.